# Explanation for Scheduling Categories in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop-yarn, scheduling, hadoop2

Trying to categorize Hadoop's schedulers (not only the official FIFO-Capacity-Fair) i seem to find that there is no clear understanding as to what each of the 4 categories that a Scheduler can belong to, are defining as a behavior control.
The 4 Categories i seem to conclude are:

**• Static Scheduling**

**• Dynamic Scheduling**

**• Resource Availability**

**• Time Awareness**

Can someone point me into a direction or a source i am not aware of, in order to find out more, or clarify on it's own the above?

Answer (score 1):

While researching into this more i came to the following conclusion, which i am posting in order to help.

A Scheduler can belong in 2 Categories. **Static Scheduling**(FIFO,Fair,Delay,Capacity) and **Dynamic Scheduling**(Deadline Constraint, Resource Aware).

After choosing the desired scheduler, the tuning of various properties inside YARN's code, can define if that Scheduler will work based on **Resource Availability**(Delay Scheduler, Matchmaking Scheduler, Resource Aware) or based in the **Time**(Deadline Constraint, Delay) constraint.

Again this is an understanding of mine through some research that i have done.